# MySQL: Subquery to get value based on another value of same column

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I'm querying the WordPress [wp_postmeta table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta) for the lowest `meta_value` of rows with the meta_key `item_thickness`:

`SELECT min(cast(meta_value as unsigned)) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='item_thickness'`

This works great.

**Question**: How would I extend this query to select the same lowest `item_thickness` from rows with the same `post_id` and with `meta_key='item_status'` and `meta_value='Raw'`

The `post_id` forms the relationship between these rows but I don't know how to do a JOIN on the same table or the proper syntax for a sub-query

This is my latest (failing) attempt at the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_postmeta 
JOIN ( 
  SELECT min(cast(meta_value as unsigned)), post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='item_thickness'
) b 
ON wp_postmeta.post_id=b.post_id
```

Comment: Many SO users will not be familiar with the WordPress database schema.  Could you let us know what columns/types the tables related to your problem have?

Comment: Link to wp_postmeta schema details added.

Comment: This query doesn't look too bad.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Not getting any errors, just not getting the right result. My latest query returns the same lowest value without checking the item_status. The same as the first query: `SELECT min(cast(meta_value as unsigned)) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='item_thickness'`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use WP_Query to build the MySQL I needed and then edit it so it would select the value I wanted.

Working query.

```
$wpdb->get_var( "SELECT min(cast(wp_postmeta.meta_value as unsigned)) FROM wp_postmeta  INNER JOIN wp_posts ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'item_thickness' AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'item_status' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'raw' )) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'inventory' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')" );
```